# Error occuring while merging value to array

Tags: php

I have a array

```
stdClass Object ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 5353 [month] => 05 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 06 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [id] => 4676 [month] => 06 ) 
   [3] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 07 ) 
   [4] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 09 ) 
)
```

I want when a key in array is duplicate, it will be added to array
This is my code:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($object as $val) {
   if(!isset($result[$val['id']])) 
      $result[$val['id']] = $val;
   else
      $result[$val['id']]['month'] = array($result[$val['id']]['month'], $val['month']);
}
$result = array_values($result); // reindex array
```

Result:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 5353 [month] => 05) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 06 [1] => 07 ) [1] => 09 ) ) 
   [2] => Array ( [id] => 4676 [month] => 06 ) 
)
```

How to fix it to result is:

```
Array ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 5353 [month] => 05) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => Array ( [0] => 06 [1] => 07 [2] => 09 ) )
   [2] => Array ( [id] => 4676 [month] => 06 ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($object as $val) {

   if( ! isset($result[$val['id']])) {
       $result[$val['id']] = $val;   
   } else if ( ! is_array($result[$val['id']]['month'])){
       $result[$val['id']]['month'] = array($result[$val['id']]['month'], $val['month']);
   } else {
       $result[$val['id']]['month'][] = $val['month'];
   }

}
$result = array_values($result);
```

but, how can you get a stdClass Object like below

```
stdClass Object ( 
   [0] => Array ( [id] => 5353 [month] => 05 ) 
   [1] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 06 ) 
   [2] => Array ( [id] => 4676 [month] => 06 ) 
   [3] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 07 ) 
   [4] => Array ( [id] => 5542 [month] => 09 ) 
)
```